# How to change lightswitch logo without Sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

How do you change the logo and/or theme when using lightswitch without sharepoint, using Visual Studio 2012?  The Properties/General Properties tab does not have the logo selection like if you are using Sharepoint.  All it has are Application Version and Default Language.

Answer (score 0):

You do this under `Edit Client properties` on the General Properties Tab:

[image: General Properties]

Then you will see the Icon/Theme:

[image: Client Properties]